# How can I restrict access to my website via web services only?

Tags: 7, services, .htaccess, advertising

I am getting lots of spam in my website. Here are some modules I tried as a remedy:

1. [Honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot)
2. [Http BL](https://www.drupal.org/project/httpbl)

No luck yet however.

Now I **decided** to make the site available only for web services only, whereas the web services are done with [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module.

So how can I allow access to my website via services only? Is there something I can achieve this from ***.htaccess*** ?

Comment: for spam control I think you can also try changing the admin url and user login url using [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths)

Comment: @shrish, good point. I'll try that too....

Comment: have you tried any sort of Captcha for anon users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume a setup like so:

- Assume that for site access via Services you use an account called "ServicesUser".
- Create a new role, say you call it "ServicesOnly".
- Make sure that there are no other "custom" roles in your site apart from anonymous, Authenticated and Administrator (if there are any: remove them again).
- Authorize only user "ServicesUser" for this role "ServicesOnly".
- Tune your permissions where appropriate, so that:

  - No permissions are granted to Anonymous or Authenticated.
  - All permissions are granted to Administrator (but only in case you have a need to ever login without using services, with a userid different from user/1, if there is no need for that, then no permissions granted to Administrator either).
- Granularly issue permissions to role "ServicesOnly", so that "ServicesUser" receives appropriate permissions whenever required.
- Whenever the site is switched to maintenance mode (eg to apply Drupal updates), ServicesUser will not be able to login either, which is what you should want also.

With a setup like above, access via Services (and userid = ServicesUser) should work as desired. While I cannot think of any other user who can do anything on your site, except user/1 (and optionally some other user who has access to role Administrator).

With this configuration, these are the only ways around it that I can think of:

- Some security issues that are exploited somehow.
- Somehow getting access to the ServicesUser account

**Note**: no additional contributed or custom) modules needed either ...